# How to assign unique values to dropdown list loaded asynchronously

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, drop-down-menu

i successfully loaded data from an API as a drop down list and i want to get the value of each option when selected. How do i assign unique values to each option? also how do i get the selected value?

HTML

```
<div class="cur-conv-container">
    <select id="conv_from"></select>
    <input type="number" name="" id="num_from">
    <br><br>
    To: 
    <select id="conv_to"></select>
    <br><br>
    <a href="#" id="conv-btn" class="btn btn-warning btn-cur-conv " onclick="convert()">Convert</a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadCurrency(){ 
    var url = "https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v6/currencies";
    var currency ;
    var allCurr;
    var currencyFrom = document.getElementById("conv_from");
    var currencyTo = document.getElementById("conv_to");

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
            currency = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
            allCurr = currency.results;
            for(x in allCurr){
            currencyFrom.innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
            currencyTo.innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
            }

        }
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: my research have been to no avail thats why i seek help here

Comment: what does the data loaded from your API look like?

Comment: Please provide all relevant code as per [mcve]

Comment: it is Currency Api so it is a list of currencies

Comment: consider including the code that shows how you are loading data from your API, the HTML relevant to your drop down, etc.

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestand your question correctly, then you're wanting to extract the `id` of each currency item returned from the API, and use that for the value of your `<select>` options.

This can be achieved by making the following changes to your `onreadystatechange` handler:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        currency = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
        allCurr = currency.results;
        for(x in allCurr){

        // Extract the currency item for current key "x"
        var currency = allCurr[x];

        // Extract currency id from current currecny item
        var currencyId = currency.id;

        // Use currencyId as value for select options being added
        currencyFrom.innerHTML += 
        "<option value='" + currencyId + "'>" + x + "</option>";
        currencyTo.innerHTML += 
        "<option value='" + currencyId + "'>" + x + "</option>";
        }

    }
}
```